# Removing lines containing a unique first field with awk?

Tags: sorting, sed, awk, grep, uniq

Looking to print only lines that have a duplicate first field. e.g. from data that looks like this:

```
1 abcd
1 efgh
2 ijkl
3 mnop
4 qrst
4 uvwx
```

Should print out:

```
1 abcd
1 efgh
4 qrst
4 uvwx
```

(FYI - first field is not always 1 character long in my data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}(a[$1] > 1)' ./infile ./infile
```

Yes, you give it the same file as input twice.  Since you don't know ahead of time if the current record is uniq or not, you build up an array based on `$1` on the first pass then you only output records that have seen `$1` more than once on the second pass.

I'm sure there are ways to do it with only a single pass through the file but I doubt they will be as "clean"

#### Explanation

1. `FNR==NR`: This is only true when `awk` is reading the first file. It essentially tests total number of records seen (NR) vs the input record in the current file (FNR).
2. `a[$1]++`: Build an associative array **a** who's key is the first field (`$1`) and who's value is incremented by one each time it's seen.
3. `next`: Ignore the rest of the script if this is reached, start over with a new input record
4. `(a[$1] > 1)` This will only be evaluated on the second pass of `./infile` and it only prints records who's first field (`$1`) we've seen more than once.  Essentially, it is shorthand for `if(a[$1] > 1){print $0}`

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat ./infile
1 abcd
1 efgh
2 ijkl
3 mnop
4 qrst
4 uvwx

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}(a[$1] > 1)' ./infile ./infile
1 abcd
1 efgh
4 qrst
4 uvwx
```

Comment: Thanks! Also I didn't know about using two file inputs to awk.

(FYI - other answers so far also work, thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some awk code to do what you want, assuming the input is grouped by its first field already (like `uniq` also requires):

```
BEGIN {f = ""; l = ""}
{
  if ($1 == f) {
    if (l != "") {
      print l
      l = ""
    }
    print $0
  } else {
    f = $1
    l = $0
  }
}
```

In this code, `f` is the previous value of field 1 and `l` is the first line of the group (or empty if that has already been printed out).

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN { IDLE = 0; DUP = 1; state = IDLE }

{ 
  if (state == IDLE) {
    if($1 == lasttime) {
       state = DUP
       print lastline
    } else state = IDLE
  } else {
    if($1 != lasttime)
        state = IDLE
  }
  if (state == DUP)
    print $0
  lasttime = $1
  lastline = $0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ordered input as you show in your question:

```
awk '$1 == prev {if (prevline) print prevline; print $0; prevline=""; next} {prev = $1; prevline=$0}' inputfile
```

The file only needs to be read once.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Ruby(1.9+)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
hash = Hash.new{|h,k|h[k] = []}
File.open("file").each do |x|
  a,b=x.split(/\s+/,2)
  hash[a] << b
end
hash.each{|k,v| hash[k].each{|y| puts "#{k} #{y}" } if v.size>1 }
```

output:

```
$ cat file
1 abcd
1 efgh
2 ijkl
3 mnop
4 qrst
4 uvwx
4 asdf
1 xzzz

$ ruby arrange.rb
1 abcd
1 efgh
1 xzzz
4 qrst
4 uvwx
4 asdf
```