# Problems combining awk scripts

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to use awk to parse a tab delimited table -- there are several duplicate entries in the first column, and I need to remove the duplicate rows that have a smaller total sum of the other 4 columns in the table. I can remove the first or second row easily, and sum the columns, but I'm having trouble combining the two. For my purposes there will never be more than 2 duplicates.

Example file: http://pastebin.com/u2GBnm2D

Desired output in this case would be to remove the rows:

```
lmo0330 1       1       0       1
lmo0506 7       21      2       10
```

And keep the other two rows with the same gene id in the column. The final parsed file would look like this: http://pastebin.com/WgDkm5ui

Here's what I have tried (this doesn't do anything. But the first part removes the second duplicate, and the second part sums the counts):

```
awk 'BEGIN {!a[$1]++} {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) t+=$i; print t; t=0}'
```

I tried modifying the 2nd part of the script in the best answer of this question: [Removing lines containing a unique first field with awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123820/removing-lines-containing-a-unique-first-field-with-awk)

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]++;next}(a[$1] > 1)' ./infile ./infile
```

But unfortunately I don't really understand what's going on well enough to get it working. Can anyone help me out? I think I need to replace the `a[$1] > 1` part with [remove (first duplicate count or 2nd duplicate count depending on which is larger].

EDIT: I'm also using GNU Awk 3.1.7 if that matters.

Comment: Your question is ok, but it is hard to understand, what do you exactly want.

Comment: i added a link to what the output would look like after parsing, does that help clarify the question?

Comment: That's a VERY old version of gawk, you should update it as you're missing a lot of extremely useful functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {
   print;
   next
} {
   s = $2+$3+$4+$5
} s >= sum[$1] {
   sum[$1] = s;
   if (!($1 in rows))
      a[++n] = $1;
   rows[$1] = $0
} END {
   for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
      print rows[a[i]]
}' file | column -t
```

**Output:**

```
gene     SRR034450.out.rpkm_0  SRR034451.out.rpkm_0  SRR034452.out.rpkm_0  SRR034453.out.rpkm_0
lmo0001  160                   323                   533                   293
lmo0002  135                   317                   504                   306
lmo0003  1                     4                     5                     3
lmo0004  35                    59                    58                    48
lmo0005  113                   218                   257                   187
lmo0006  279                   519                   653                   539
lmo0007  563                   1053                  1165                  1069
lmo0008  34                    84                    203                   107
lmo0009  13                    45                    90                    49
lmo0010  57                    210                   237                   169
lmo0011  65                    224                   247                   179
lmo0012  65                    226                   250                   215
lmo0013  342                   500                   738                   682
lmo0014  662                   1032                  1283                  1311
lmo0015  321                   413                   631                   637
lmo0016  175                   253                   273                   325
lmo0017  3                     6                     6                     6
lmo0018  33                    38                    46                    45
lmo0019  13                    1                     39                    1
lmo0020  3                     12                    28                    15
lmo0021  3                     4                     14                    12
lmo0022  2                     3                     5                     1
lmo0023  2                     0                     3                     2
lmo0024  1                     0                     2                     6
lmo0330  1                     1                     1                     3
lmo0506  151                   232                   60                    204
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll run it tomorrow

Comment: Never seen indentation/formatting quite like that - cut/paste problem?

Comment: Welp...This doesn't work as expected. Here's my complete file: http://pastebin.com/hPnBw8RU  and the output file from running the awk script: http://pastebin.com/6ghVFVDK ... somehow its removing gene names that are not duplicates, and i do not know why :/ there are only 3 duplicates in this example.

Comment: Ah that's right. We need `s >= sum[$1]` instead of `s > sum[$1]`. See updated answer.